# Example or docs for LiveScript scope

Tags: livescript

Am just starting out with Livescript and want to know how the scope works.

Are the any good example/docs that show all scope symbols and usage.
Symbols like:

- @
- -> vs ~>
- self
- :=

### Edit

The problem I face:

[This ethercalc code](https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc/blob/master/src/sc.ls): line 103.
 I want to insert a call to a Java script function, i.e. to [this send email code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901445/why-is-oauth2-with-gmail-nodejs-nodemailer-producing-username-and-password-not).

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @gkz see the edit with links to the livescript code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://livescript.net documents all that functionality.

- `@` means `this`.
- `@prop` means `this.prop`
- `->` creates a function, it means `function(){}`
- `-> blah()` is `function(){ return blah(); }`
- `(a, b) -> foo` is `function(a, b) { return foo; }`
- `self` is nothing special, just the name of a variable. Often set to `this` of an upper scope.
- `:=` means "reassign a variable" - it must already exist. It does not create a new variable.
  Check out http://livescript.net/#introduction for more info